# Program not encrypting properly with spaces

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography

I have tried to create an implementation of a vigenere cipher, but have come across a hurde in the form of the program not working properly when given spaces in the input. (Assume keyword bacon)
**With Spaces**

Input

> Meet me

Correct Output

> Negh zf

Actual Output

> Negh Ne

**Without Spaces**

Input

> Meetme

Ouput

> Neghzf

So clearly the program is working for strings without the spaces. Anywhere here is the code and thanks in advance for help.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
char encrypt(int key, char a);
int hash(char a);
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("You need a keyword!");
        return 1;
    }

    string keyword = argv[1];

    for (int j = 0; j != strlen(keyword); ++j)
    {
        if (!isalpha(keyword[j]))
        {
            printf ("The keyword needs to be all words!");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    string text = GetString();

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i != strlen(text); ++i, ++j)
    {
        if (j == strlen(keyword))
        {
            j = 0;
        }

        int key = 0;

        if (isupper(keyword[j]))
        {
            key = keyword[j] - 'A';
            text[i] = encrypt(key, text[i]);
        }
        else if (islower(keyword[j]))
        {
            key = keyword[j] - 'a';
            text[i] = encrypt(key, text[i]);
        }
        else if (isspace(text[i]))
        {
            j = j - 1;
        }

    }

    printf ("%s\n", text);
}
char encrypt(int key, char a)
{
    if (isalpha(a))
    {
        int total = (int) a + key;
        if (isupper(a))
        {
            while (total > 90)
            {
                total = total - 26;
            }
        }
        else if (islower(a))
        {
            while (total > 122)
            {
                total = total - 26;
            }
        }

        return (char) total;
    }
    else
    {
        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: `printf ("The keyword needs to be all words!");` seems pretty concise, lol.

Comment: @cad -- I thought you were joking at first, but now I'm wondering if we weren't saying the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is inside your for loop. Try to correct it in the following way (you will understand easily the mistake):

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i != strlen(text); ++i, ++j)
{
    if (j == strlen(keyword))
    {
        j = 0;
    }
    // the following check mmust be done here
    if (isspace(text[i])) {
        j = j - 1;
    }
    int key = 0;
    if (isupper(keyword[j]))
    {
        key = keyword[j] - 'A';
        text[i] = encrypt(key, text[i]);
    }
    else if (islower(keyword[j]))
    {
        key = keyword[j] - 'a';
        text[i] = encrypt(key, text[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are reading your words from command line arguments; however, command line arguments are typically separated by whitespace. Your program doesn't know that those spaces are supposed to be part of the input.

You need to change the way you are reading input.

Comment: on the command line I can pass a string with spaces. It's only required to use the double quotes like "this is a word" for the argument

Comment: well...you may want to edit your question because you don't show any quotations in your example input

Comment: if the name of the executable file is for instance z.out the way to pass as an argument a string with spaces is:  z.out  "this is a string".   Instead if you are referring to my answer the mistake is enough clear: the check on the withe spaces must be done before the coding. Thanks so much for your suggestion.